# Was Fenoglio based on any real author?

Tags: inspiration, inkheart-trilogy

Cornelia Funke's fantasy series beginning with the novel *Inkheart* features a character named Fenoglio, an old man who wrote a fantasy novel called *Inkheart*.

**Was Fenoglio based on, or inspired by, any real fantasy author(s)?**

Since this is an issue where, if the answer is yes, Funke might not necessarily admit it (for obvious reasons), I would accept answers based on *either* "canon" evidence such as author interviews *or* (for me more interesting) a solid evidence-based analysis connecting Fenoglio with a real author.

Comment: You may be interested to know that [Beppe Fenoglio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beppe_Fenoglio) was an Italian writer (even if not a fantasy author). But since I haven't read the Inkheart trilogy, I don't know if it is a coincidence or there is a reason why she named the character as him

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In an answer to one of the [questions](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/586740-hi-cornelia-another-question-i-always) in a question and answer thread on Goodreads, Funke replied:

> I based Fenoglio on Beppe Fenoglio, a short story writer from Liguria,
> who died much too young. And of course I made him my Alter Ego, when
> he thinks about writing.

So the coincidence of the name with [Beppe Fenoglio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beppe_Fenoglio) already noted in the comments, is not a coincidence.